# ¿Qué significa "Cada vez que alguien habla, sube el pan"?

Tags: expresiones

No entiendo el significado de la expresión:

> Cada vez que [alguien] habla, sube el pan

No he encontrado una explicación en fuente fiable. ¿Alguien podría aportar explicación y a poder ser, fuente fiable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Básicamente significa "cada vez que habla produce gran descontento (social) y/o preocupación".

Esa "subida del pan" es un situación (figurada) poco deseable que enfurece a la gente. Cuando el precio de la luz, el gas, los impuestos, etc. ("el pan") sube todos los ciudadanos nos enfadamos y nos preocupamos.

Imagínate a esa figura medianamente conocida (un político o un *famosete*, alguien de mucha relevancia) que hace unas declaraciones públicas desacertadas, y casi todo el mundo protesta o se burla de él/ella (cosa cada vez más frecuente en las redes sociales) una y otra vez, o la gente empieza a preocuparse ("qué ha querido decir?", "Se perderán puestos de trabajo?", "Va a subir la gasolina *otra vez*?").

Especialmente con los políticos, que tienen cargos de responsabilidad, cuando no miden bien sus palabras o estas se sacan de contexto, aquello de dicen puede causar un efecto o reacción inesperados (por ejemplo haciendo que los mercados suban o bajen).

Esa persona dice algo y produce gran malestar y descontento social en general. Vuelve a pronunciarse (con otra cosa, o para matizar o aclarar sus palabras anteriores) y lo empeora todavía más. Luego dice algo sobre otra cosa no tan relacionada y también mete la pata hasta el fondo.

Al final alguien dice "cada vez que esta persona habla, la caga" o "sube el pan" (nos lo pone más difícil).

También se puede aplicar a una persona no famosa, si por ejemplo dices algo con la intención de ayudar a alguien y terminas empeorándolo todo. Por ejemplo, mis amigos Fulanito y Fulanita están peleados y yo voy e intento mediar y arreglar las cosas con poco tino y terminan más peleados y cabreados todavía (por mi falta de destreza al intentar arreglar las cosas, más que intencionalidad). Al final alguien me diría "Cállate ya, que cada vez que hablas sube el pan".

Answer (score -1):

Sus declaraciones causan tanta preocupación que la gente acumula productos y estos suben deprecio.